# Boot option showing 2x HDD with same name when I only have 1x SSD installed in my notebook

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, ssd, uefi

I have installed Pop OS on the only SSD I have in my laptop, but when I enter boot options, I see two HDD devices with the same name - is this normal? Did encrypting the SSD during the OS installation cause this?

**UEFI Boot Options:** [image: bios image showing 2 HDD]

```
$ efibootmgr -v

  BootCurrent: 0001
  Timeout:     0 seconds
  BootOrder:   0001,0000,2001,2002,2003

  Boot0000* EFI Hard Drive (KXG60ZNV512G TOSHIBA)   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,8C-E3-8E-03-00-44-5A-F8)/HD(1,GPT,2a0e675f-f83d-4a27-9f3a-c607de150860,0x1000,0x1fefff)RC
  Boot0001* Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS   HD(1,GPT,2a0e675f-f83d-4a27-9f3a-c607de150860,0x1000,0x1fefff)/File(\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi)
  Boot2001* EFI USB Device  RC
  Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM   RC
  Boot2003* EFI Network RC
```

**Disk Management:**

- [image: screenshot1] [image: screenshot 2] [image: screenshot 3]

I've deleted the redundant entry with the command "sudo efibootmgr -b  -B".the terminal output says the entry is deleted but when i reboot the entry reappears. Here is the output:

```
alex@pop-os:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
[sudo] password di alex: 
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* EFI Hard Drive (KXG60ZNV512G TOSHIBA) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,8C-E3-8E-03-00-44-5A-F8)/HD(1,GPT,2a0e675f-f83d-4a27-9f3a-c607de150860,0x1000,0x1fefff)RC
Boot0001* Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS HD(1,GPT,2a0e675f-f83d-4a27-9f3a-c607de150860,0x1000,0x1fefff)/File(\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
alex@pop-os:~$ sudo efibootmgr -b 0000 -B
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
alex@pop-os:~$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS HD(1,GPT,2a0e675f-f83d-4a27-9f3a-c607de150860,0x1000,0x1fefff)/File(\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
alex@pop-os:~$
```

So it looks like the problem is solved but when i reboot the 0000 redundant entry appears again.

Comment: Do you have two bootable partitions on the device or two bootable entries within the same boot partition?

Comment: Can you add to your post a screenshot of the entire window of Disk Management?

Comment: @JW0914 I'm not sure about that, but i don't think so.

Comment: @harrymc i've just added the screenshots

Comment: Please also attach `sudo efibootmgr -v` output [to the question](https://superuser.com/posts/1801740/edit). Please, paste it **AS TEXT** copypaste, not as a screenshot.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I've just edited the question with the output

Answer (score 3):

There are two EFI boot entries both pointing to the same EFI System Partition on your single device:

```
Boot0000* ... HD(1,GPT,2a0e675f-f83d-4a27-9f3a-c607de150860,0x1000,0x1fefff) ...
Boot0001* ... HD(1,GPT,2a0e675f-f83d-4a27-9f3a-c607de150860,0x1000,0x1fefff) ...
```

What you see in the boot selection menu are EFI boot entries, not devices. So it's normal it appeared twice. BootCurrent is 0001; you can use efibootmgr to remove unused boot entry `Boot0000`:

```
sudo efibootmgr -B -b Boot0000
```

Or, in some cases you can remove this entry using BIOS setup utility.

A redundant entry should disappear from the EFI boot selection menu.

Comment: I've deleted the redundant entry with the command you suggested me, and the output in the terminal says the entry is indeed deleted. But when i reboot the entry reappears for some reason. I've edited thr question with the output of my terminal.

Comment: Well, it looks like firmware adds it back. Can you describe your hardware (exact model) and the firmware it runs (e.g. Insyde or something else, and which version), and the settings regarding boot settings? E.g. whether CSM, legacy BIOS boot, secure boot is enabled or not?

Comment: i've tried to reinstall PopOS and the redundant entry was still there. Today i decided to switch to Linux Mint and now it's showing only one HDD like it should. So maybe it was a PopOs problem.

Comment: I doubt that. The Pop OS boot entry I saw from your previous update looks pretty fine to me. I'd serous about some firmware configuration or bug causing this.